# unable to load module /usr/local/lib/libsst.so

Tags: openssl, debian, pkcs#11

I had the problem described here: [PKCS#11 engine does not work in openssl on centos 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052171/pkcs11-engine-does-not-work-in-openssl-on-centos-6)

So I tried to apply the solution, with my paths:

```
engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre MODULE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/libsst.so
```

But I don't have libsst.so anywhere. Can't figure the right package to install.

So the previous command line ends with:

```
Loaded: (pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
unable to load module /usr/local/lib/libsst.so
[ unavailable ]
```

Debian version: 6.0.10

What do I need to install?

Comment: I think this is probably a typo. I added a comment to that question. My guess is that it should be `libssl.so`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha In this case I just made copy paste. It seeks for libsst.so

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).