# Where is engine_pkcs11.so?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11, yubikey, opensc, hardware-security-module

I'm trying to run openssl in combination with a PKCS#11 hardware security module (currently trying with Yubikey 5). All documentation and tutorials I find tell me that I have to use OpenSC as "engine", and the openssl command always look [something](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11#:%7E:text=OpenSSL%3E%20engine%20%2Dt%20dynamic%20%2Dpre%20SO_PATH%3A/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2Dpre%20ID%3Apkcs11%20%2Dpre%20LIST_ADD%3A1%20%2Dpre%20LOAD%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2Dpre%20MODULE_PATH%3Aopensc%2Dpkcs11.so) [like](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Certificate_authority.html#:%7E:text=usr/lib/engines/-,engine_pkcs11.so,-%2Dpre%20ID%3Apkcs11) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185961/5226287):

```
OpenSSL> engine -t dynamic -pre SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so
         -pre ID:pkcs11 -pre LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD 
         -pre MODULE_PATH:opensc-pkcs11.so
```

But where do I get this **engine_pkcs11.so** from? I cannot find it in any package of [any distribution](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=engine_pkcs11.so&on=files). I found the [OpenSC/engine_pkcs11](https://github.com/OpenSC/engine_pkcs11) repo, but the README states that this library has been merged into [OpenSC/libp11](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11). But the latter also doesn't seem to provide this library after compiling it.

Is it named differently now? Which .so file shall I provide to the `-pre SO_PATH:` argument of `openssl engine`?

Comment: According to https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11#copying-the-engine-shared-object-to-the-proper-location the 'recommended' name in the engines directory is `libpkcs11.so` -- and in Ubuntu (20.04 focal, yeah I'm lazy) it's actually `pkcs11.so` plus a _symlink_ from `libpkcs11.so` in [`libengine-pkcs11-openssl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libengine-pkcs11-openssl)

Comment: Keep in mind the way this works, is that there are two .so files in play -- the first is the engine, provided by OpenSC, which is really just a shim/wrapper around the second, and bridges "openssl" semantics to "pkcs11" function calls into the provider.  The SO_PATH variable is the engine. The second .so is usually going to be provided by the HSM/token vendor.  The Utimaco SecurityServer provider is called "libcs_pkcs11_R3.so", so the MODULE_PATH would point to that.  I don't know what Yubi's provider is called, sorry.

Comment: Thanks dave, that solved it! I can't understand though why all documentation is wrong... Anyway, if you add your comment as answer, I'll happily mark it as answer.

Comment: @rip..., thanks for the explanation. Yubico suggests to use opensc-pkcs11.so (see https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/Certificate_authority.html). So there must be some generic interface also between the second library and the hardware.